# What is the most efficient way to put together a data.frame in R with data generated by a while loop?

Tags: r, dataframe, optimization

If I run the code below:

```
i <- 0

out1 <- data.frame()

time_1 <- system.time({
  
  while (i < 10000) {
    i <- i + 1
    out1 <- rbind(out1, data.frame("i" = i, "i_squared" = i*i, "list_i" = I(list((i-3):i)), stringsAsFactors = F))
  }
  
})

cat("\ntime_1 =", time_1)

time_2 <- system.time({
  
  out2 <- sapply(1:10000, function(i) {
    data.frame("i" = i, "i_squared" = i*i, "list_i" = I(list((i-3):i)), stringsAsFactors = F)
  }, simplify = F)
  
  out2 <- do.call(rbind,out2)
})

cat("\ntime_2 =", time_2)

time_3 <- system.time({
  
  out3 <- sapply(1:10000, function(i) {
    c("i" = i, "i_squared" = i*i, "list_i" = I(list((i-3):i)))
  }, simplify = F)
  
  out3 <- do.call(rbind,out3)
})

cat("\ntime_3 =", time_3)
```

I get the following:

```
time_1 = 9.39 0.01 9.44 NA NA
time_2 = 3.42 0 3.43 NA NA
time_3 = 0.18 0 0.17 NA NA
```

So `sapply` followed by `rbind` is better than `rbind`-ing rows sequentially, and the last method is much faster by orders of magnitude.

However, there are 2 issues, for my actual case.

1. I have a `while` loop in my code, where `i` is manipulated in complex ways, i.e. I don't know upfront which or how many values `i` will take. Thus I cannot use `sapply`.
2. The last method does not work, because the data I need to output do not only contain single numeric values, but also lists of values (which in the first 2 examples I forced by `I(list())`.

Can anyone suggest how I could obtain `out1` by a faster process than the one in example 1, and in a way that is compatible with the requirement that `i` is not known upfront?

**EDIT** - based on Ronak Shah's suggestion combined with example 3 above

```
# Ronak Shah's suggestion

i <- 0

out4 <- vector('list', 10000L)
time_4 <- system.time({
  
  while (i < 10000) {
    i <- i + 1
    out4[[i]] <- data.frame("i" = i, 
                              "i_squared" = i*i, 
                              "list_i" = I(list((i-3):i)), stringsAsFactors = F)
  }
  out4 <- do.call(rbind, out4)
})

cat("\ntime_4 =", time_4)

# Combination of 3 and 4

i <- 0

out5 <- vector('list', 10000L)
time_5 <- system.time({
  
  while (i < 10000) {
    i <- i + 1
    out5[[i]] <- c("i" = i, "i_squared" = i*i, "list_i" = paste((i-3):i,collapse=","))
    }
  out5 <- do.call(rbind, out5)
  out5 <- as.data.frame(out5, stringsAsFactors = F)
  out5["i"] <- as.integer(out5$i)
  out5["i_squared"] <- as.integer(out5$i_squared)
  #out5["list_i"] <- do.call(rbind,sapply(out5$list_i,function(csl) I(list(as.integer(unlist(strsplit(csl,split=","))))),simplify = F))
})

cat("\ntime_5 =", time_5)
```

As mentioned in my comment below, example 5 is much faster, but the bit where the column of comma-delimited characters is turned back into a column of vectors does not work. It complains about the different size of the replacement.
I suspect the reason is that `rbind` turns the `sapply` output into a matrix. I think this was discussed before. I will see if I can find how to solve it.

**EDIT 2**

OK, I might have a solution; although the result is not `identical(out1,out5)`:

```
i <- 0

out5 <- vector('list', 10000L)
time_5 <- system.time({
  
  while (i < 10000) {
    i <- i + 1
    out5[[i]] <- c("i" = i, "i_squared" = i*i, "list_i" = paste((i-3):i,collapse=","))
    }
  out5 <- do.call(rbind, out5)
  out5 <- as.data.frame(out5, stringsAsFactors = F)
  out5["i"] <- as.integer(out5$i)
  out5["i_squared"] <- as.integer(out5$i_squared)
  out5$list_i <- unname(sapply(out5$list_i,function(csl) I(as.integer(unlist(strsplit(csl,split=",")))),simplify = F))
})

cat("\ntime_5 =", time_5)
```

The identity of `out5` and `out1` fails, as mentioned:

```
sapply(out1,class)
#        i i_squared    list_i 
#"numeric" "numeric"    "AsIs" 
sapply(out5,class)
#        i i_squared    list_i 
#"integer" "integer"    "list"
```

I don't know what causes this difference... :(
And it seems strange that one should go via a character matrix to speed things up.

But OK, it looks like `out5` contains what I need, and I achieved the desired big reduction in run time, so I would call this "problem solved".
Thanks again Ronak Shah for your help!

**EDIT 3** - after further work

In fact, it looks like there is no need to `paste` and then `strsplit`: it is possible to add items of the form `c(integer, integer, I(list(integers)) )` to the `list` suggested by Ronak Shah.

So here are two ~equally fast solutions, one using `sapply`, for when one is sure to fill all 10000 rows, and one appending items to the pre-made `list`.
*NOTE: I replaced each occurrence of `list((i-3):i)` by `ifelse(i/2 == floor(i/2),  list((i-3):i), list((i-2):i) )`, to simulate the real cases where the length of the list of integers differs in each row.*

```
time_6 <- system.time({
  
  out6 <- sapply(1:10000, function(i) {
    c("i" = i, "i_squared" = i*i, "list_i" = I(ifelse(i/2 == floor(i/2),  list((i-3):i), list((i-2):i) )))
  }, simplify = F)
  
  out6 <- do.call(rbind,out6)
  out6 <- as.data.frame(out6, stringsAsFactors = F)
  out6["i"] <- unlist(out6$i)
  out6["i_squared"] <- unlist(out6$i_squared)
})

cat("\ntime_6 =", time_6)

i <- 0

out7 <- vector('list', 10000L)
time_7 <- system.time({
  
  while (i < 10000) {
    i <- i + 1
    out7[[i]] <- c("i" = i, "i_squared" = i*i, "list_i" = I(ifelse(i/2 == floor(i/2),  list((i-3):i), list((i-2):i) )))
  }
  
  out7 <- do.call(rbind,out7)
  out7 <- as.data.frame(out7, stringsAsFactors = F)
  out7["i"] <- unlist(out7$i)
  out7["i_squared"] <- unlist(out7$i_squared)
})

cat("\ntime_7 =", time_7)
```

Run times are the following:

```
time_1 = 6.65 0.08 7.16 NA NA
time_2 = 2.28 0.01 2.29 NA NA
time_3 = 0.18 0 0.17 NA NA
time_4 = 2.35 0.02 2.36 NA NA
time_5 = 0.3 0.02 0.32 NA NA
time_6 = 0.15 0.01 0.18 NA NA
time_7 = 0.17 0 0.18 NA NA
```

What's especially good in method 7 is that the data are not converted forth and back, they are integers to start with and remain integers throughout. After applying `as.data.frame`, it is sufficient to `unlist` the columns that are not supposed to be lists. The other column, made as a list, is indeed a list and can remain such.

I just wonder if/why there isn't more documentation about this. I am pretty sure people often have to create `data.frame`'s by appending rows generated by some iterative process. Does everybody have to reinvent the wheel every time?

Comment: In case you know the dimensions and the type is equal store it in a matrix: `m <- matrix(0, 6, 10000); for(i in 1:10000) {m[,i] <- c(i, i*i, (i-3):i)}`

Comment: No, I can't do this, because the final structure is not what I need. I need a `data.frame` like `out5` as output. Also, in this simple example all the elements of `list_i` have the same number of integers, but in my real application they don't, so `matrix` would complain. But I have found now that `out3` can be adapted to my needs. I will post it now.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that you are going to have 1000 rows in your data initialise a list with that length which will significantly improve the performance.

Using your method I get the time as :

```
cat("\ntime_1 =", time_1)

time_1 = 8.42 1.158 9.628 0 0
```

Initialising the length of the list I get :

```
i <- 1
result <- vector('list', 1000L)
time_1 <- system.time({
  
  while (i < 10000) {
    i <- i + 1
    result[[i]] <- data.frame("i" = i, 
                              "i_squared" = i*i, 
                              "list_i" = I(list((i-3):i)), stringsAsFactors = F)
  }
  out1 <- do.call(rbind, result)
})

cat("\ntime_1 =", time_1)

time_1 = 2.243 0.011 2.262 0 0
```

Comment: Thank you; would it work even when the initial number of elements is larger than what I get in the end, meaning, would the empty elements be ignored? BTW, there must be something not correct; when I run this code I get an empty out1.

Comment: Yes, that would work even for larger number of elements. Run `i <- 1` first and then run the above to get result in `out1`.

Comment: OK, thanks! In my system, this takes about the same time as the sapply version (example 2). If it cannot be improved any further, OK, then I'll use this. It's a pity that the last method cannot be adapted, as that would be very fast. Maybe I could turn the lists into comma-separated characters using paste, and apply strsplit on the output. Not sure if it's efficient though.

Comment: Actually it works: if I use method 3 combined with your suggestion to predefine an empty list, it's as fast as sapply. Yes, then I have a character matrix that I need to reformat to a data.frame and split, but hey, it's worth it. Thank you very much again! I will post the solution as an edit in my own post, for future reference.

Comment: I see now that I cannot write the last bit where the pasted column is turned back into a column of integer vectors. I will see if I can solve that and share it.